# Non blank cell count for a particular row in dynamic colums in ssrs with matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a SQL query like this

```
SELECT sam.AREATOPICID, 
       sec.SURVEYSECTION, 
       us.USERSURVEYID, 
       us.SURVEYAREATOPICID, 
       us.USERID, 
       usr.SURVEYUSERNAME, 
       us.COMMENT 
FROM   USERSURVEY us 
       INNER JOIN USERS usr 
               ON us.USERID = usr.USERID 
       INNER JOIN SURVEYAREATOPICMAPDEMO sam 
               ON sam.AREATOPICID = us.SURVEYAREATOPICID 
       INNER JOIN SECTION sec 
               ON sam.SURVEYSECTIONID = sec.SURVEYSECTIONID 
ORDER  BY us.USERID, 
          sam.AREATOPICID, 
          SURVEYSECTION
```

Now, in SSRS I want to display report like this

[image]
Now for comment, I want in a particular row how many users have comment on it. This field only have to show count of comments that are not blank and for a particular row(i.e. question).

I have done for user1, user2 .., type of column but I am not able to count the comment.

Comment: I don't u nderstand your layout, can you describe what should one row represent and what should one column represent. Second, you can use `sum(yourColumn)` along with groupingin your SQL query to get the sum.

Comment: one row represent the one question and in colums all the users as (a,test,sdsd) are there. Now in this matrix all the users that have comment on it are showni. It can be blank. Now Comment_count Column shows tolal no. of non blank comment for a particlar question by all users.

Comment: You should update your question with note that you are using matrix functionality.

Comment: thanks. I have updated it.

Comment: Did you read the answer? Was that helpful? Is there something I have to clarify further?

Comment: can you provide me expression for (sum(COMMENT)). Comment is a varchar field.

Comment: it is not giving the correct value i.e. total no. of non blank comments for a particular user. May be this is because of user field as it genrate n no. of user column. its expression is like this.=First(Fields!Comment.Value) i am not able to apply count on this.

Comment: I've added a section of answer to count non-blank comments...

Comment: SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Comment.Value) OR (Fields!Comment.Value = ""),0,1)) giving me the value for a particular cell in a column as 0 or 1. But I want total of all these values. May be I am not able to use Add total in a right way.

Comment: This is not true. This expression works as follows: for each comment it checks if it is empty, and then if it is - it counts **in sum** as 1; otherwise as 0. That way it sums non-empty comments in your total.

Comment: very true.. But is it works fine as my expression for users is =First(Fields!Comment.Value). it generates dynamic user columns. I am getting only 1 or 0 for every user column field generated. i.e. user1comment o user2Comment 1 user3Comment 1

Comment: Are there in your database any multiple nonempty comments for the same user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your matrix, there are row (your question), column (your user) and a data cell  (sum(COMMENT))in it. Right-click it and you should get `Add Total` menu item. Use it to add a column total. Then you can position that column to an appropriate location in your table.

**EDIT**

For counting records you use COUNT() like `COUNT(Fields!Comment.Value)`

For counting non-empty/null values use:

```
SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Comment.Value) OR (Fields!Comment.Value = ""),0,1))
```

Comment: I Add a new column and assign expression =Sum(Fields!Comment.Value) to it but it is showing error as comment is text value.

Comment: really thanks got the right answer. Error is in my db dublicate id's. i.e. why i am not able to get count right. Thanks a lot